# Regarding deleting a node in linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm writing code to delete a node of a list and I'm getting problem which I'm not able to figure out.

This my `delete_node` function:

```
public void delete_node(int data){
    node ptr=head;
    //if 1st node is to be Deleted
    if(ptr != null && ptr.data==data){
        head=ptr.link;
        ptr.link=null;
    }

    //line 90 below:
    while(ptr.link.data!=data){
        ptr=ptr.link;
    }

    ptr.link=ptr.link.link;

}
```

This is the `main` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    list o=new list();
    o.insert_beginning(1);
    o.insert_beginning(2);

    o.delete_node(2);//line 8

    o.display();
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at list.delete_node(list.java:90)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: you set your `ptr.link` to `null` and then try to access it's data in line 90, which is what causes your error. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reaching the end of your list without finding the `node` you want to delete. Basically trying to delete a `node` not in the list. You also access `ptr.link.data` without checking if `ptr.link` is even valid. Both of these can be remedied as follows:

```
public void delete_node(int data){
    node ptr=head;
    if(ptr == null)
        return;
    //if 1st node is to be Deleted
    if(ptr != null && ptr.data==data){
        head=ptr.link;
        ptr.link=null;
    }

    while(ptr.link != null && ptr.link.data!=data){
        ptr=ptr.link;
    }
    if(ptr.link != null)
        ptr.link=ptr.link.link;

}
```

This just checks for `ptr` being null initially, e.g. the list is empty. It also has checks for `ptr.link` being null.

---

Just a note, classes in Java are [typically uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119757/are-class-names-allowed-to-be-lower-case), e.g. `List` and `Node`.

Comment: the problem is while Deleting the 2nd node it's completely alright but while i try to delete the 1st one, it throws error. THANK U

Comment: @DeviPrasad Yea, you had another issue. Edited, should work now.

Comment: Thank u So much .