# Make a compareTo override failure, simple class

Tags: java, compareto

I have simple class with 2 fields. I want to be able to sort objects of this class so I implement a compareTo() method. The field I want to use for sorting is an int. So my method is pretty simple ..

```
public int compareTo(macToPortMapping pnum) {
    // we want to be able to sort a mapping based upon the port number
    return this.portNo - pnum.portNo;
}
```

This seems consistent with everything I've read about implementing a comparable. Still the netbeans wants to remove @Override and my compile message "method does not override a method from a supertype"..

This doesn't mean anything to me. Any pointers?

Comment: Did you implement `Comparable<macToPortMapping>`?  Also, by convention, Java class names are capitalized, e.g. MacToPortMapping.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save yourself the trouble of creating a class simply to compare _one_ field by doing `myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(macToPortMapping::portNo));` or if it's an array --->`Arrays.sort(myArray, Comparator.comparingInt(macToPortMapping::portNo));`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution -- 
in my class declaration I had to include an implements..

```
public class macToPortMapping implements Comparable<macToPortMapping>{
    int portNo;
    macAddress addr;
```

}

when I put that on the class, it all worked as expected. I don't know how I missed that in the reading.

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, yes. As a side note, you should always name your classes with capital first letter. For example here `macToPortMapping` should be `MacToPortMapping` and `macAddress` should be `MacAddress`. That is the Java convention. See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119757/are-class-names-allowed-to-be-lower-case